# qsort(): Sorting only even numbers of an array

Tags: c, sorting

I'm trying to use the `qsort()` function in order to sort only the even numbers of an array (the odds remains in their positions).

For instance if I have the array:

```
5 122 3 26 48
```

After sorting one would get:

```
5 26 3 48 122
```

My intuition was only to make a sort when both numbers pointed by `a` and `b` are even.

This is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp_even(const void *a, const void *b) {
    int l = *(int *)a;
    int r = *(int *)b;

    if ( !(l&1) && !(r&1) ) //if both are even, then sort them in ascending order
        return (l-r);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int i, n;
    int a[1001];

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    qsort(a, n, sizeof(int), comp_even);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible with a general comparison-based sort such as `qsort`.

Comment: copy => sort => writeback

Comment: How do you expect `6 5 4 3 2 1` to be sorted? `2 4 6 5 3 1` or `2 5 4 3 6 1`? That is, must every odd number remain at the same index in the array? Or do they only have to be sorted the same relative to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible to design a comparison function for your purpose, but you can make a copy of the even numbers, sort that with `qsort` and dispatch the sorted subset over the even numbers of the original array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int comp_int(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *ap = a;
    const int *bp = b;
    return (*ap > *bp) - (*ap < *bp);
}

int main(void) {
    int i, j, n, n_even;
    int a[1001];
    int even[1001];

    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n <= 0 || n > 1001)
        return 1;

    n_even = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if ((a[i] & 1) == 0) {
            even[n_even++] = a[i];
        }
    }

    qsort(even, n_even, sizeof(int), comp_int);

    for (i = j = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if ((a[i] & 1) == 0) {
            a[i] = even[j++];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that your original comparison function uses a trick to compare integers that fails for large values.  The difference of 2 integers may be outside the range of `int`. So returning `l - r` may be incorrect for many values of `l` and `r`.

For example `l=INT_MIN` and `r=1` will return `INT_MIN-1`, the subtraction causes an arithmetic overflow, which invokes undefined behavior and in current 2s complement architectures evaluates to `INT_MAX`, a positive value although `INT_MIN < 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, `qsort` doesn't support anything like that; for any two elements, the comparison function must return one of three results:

- a negative integer, meaning that its first argument should end up *before* its second;
- a positive integer, meaning that its first argument should end up *after* its second;
- zero, meaning that either ordering is fine (in which case `qsort` makes no guarantees about which element ends up before the other).

And, crucially, the function must do this using only the values of its two arguments; it doesn't know the array-indices that they came from.

Instead, you can take one of two approaches:

- copy all of the even elements into an array, sort that array using a straightforward comparison function, and then copy the elements of that array back over the even elements in the original array.
- create an `int[][2]` that stores not just the values in the array, but also their original indices. You can then sort the elements such that if either value is odd, then the element with the lesser original index comes first.

Comment: The comparison function can actually find out what array indices the elements come from, since it receives pointers to the elements. But it isn't allowed to make use of this information: for example, for an array `a = {2, 3, 2}`, the comparison function is not allowed to return different results when called on `(&a[0], &a[1])` vs `(&a[2], &a[1])`; if it returns different results, the behavior is undefined, and in practice it might result in an unsorted array or an infinite loop.

Comment: @Gilles: The second half of your comment (which is correct) contradicts the first half of your comment (which is not). The reason that the comparison function is not allowed to consider the locations of its arguments, and that you can get bizarre results if it does, is that the locations of its arguments do *not* always represent the original locations of those elements in the array. As the sort proceeds, the elements get moved around, and naturally the comparison function is always given their *current* positions.

Comment: Sure, the comparison function finds out the position at which the element currently is, not the initial position. (Actually, it doesn't — there's no guarantee that the element hasn't been copied to temporary storage — but in practice the pointer is to an array element in most implementations.) But someone reading your answer might conclude “hey, I'll make use of the pointer values and arrange to always return a value that tells `qsort` not to move the elements if one of them is odd”. Which wouldn't work, because `qsort` might move the elements anyway, or might have moved them already.